# Ruby on Rails 4 Essential Training Error ActionController::ParameterMissing in SubjectsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working through Ruby on Rails 4 Essential Training from Lynda.com and I'm running in this error:

ActionController::ParameterMissing in SubjectsController#create

I basically have a form with 3 inputs, :name, :position, and :visible. I can enter the the information just fine but then I get the error when I hit the submit button. Here is the output from the server:

```html
   `Started POST "/subjects/create" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-11 18:02:12 -0500
Processing by SubjectsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"√", "authenticity_token"=>"f6+AdWN3jWO6mL9jrPDgVGoAm/NTBF1GPxGasTaqMh0=", "subject"=>{"name"
=>"Default", "position"=>"5", "visible"=>"false"}, "commit"=>"Create Subject"}
   (0.0ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO `subjects` (`created_at`, `name`, `position`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2014-11-11 23:02:12'
, 'Default', 5, '2014-11-11 23:02:12')
   (4931.3ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/subjects/create?actions=index
Completed 302 Found in 4941ms (ActiveRecord: 4932.3ms)


Started GET "/subjects/create?actions=index" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-11 18:02:17 -0500
Processing by SubjectsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"actions"=>"index"}
Completed 400 Bad Request in 1ms

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: subject):
  app/controllers/subjects_controller.rb:40:in `subject_params'
  app/controllers/subjects_controller.rb:18:in `create'
```

```html
SubjectsController

    class SubjectsController < ApplicationController

  layout false

  def index
    @subjects = Subject.sorted
  end

  def show
    @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @subject = Subject.new({:name => "Default"})
  end

  def create
    @subject = Subject.new(subject_params)
    if @subject.save

      redirect_to(:actions => 'index')
      # raise params.inspect
    else
      render('new')
    end
  end


  def edit
  end

  def delete
  end

  private
    def subject_params
      # same as using "params[:subject]", except that it:
      # - raises an error if :subject is not present
      # - allows listed attributes to be mass-assigned
      params.require(:subject).permit(:name, :position, :visible)
    end


end
```

Looking at the server output it doesn't look like I'm passing the :visible attribute to the database even though the data shows up on the index page even after the error.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t think `:visible` is the problem, looking at your logs, you are getting this error:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: subject):
  app/controllers/subjects_controller.rb:40:in `subject_params'
  app/controllers/subjects_controller.rb:18:in `create'
```

This is because of this line:

```
Started GET "/subjects/create?actions=index" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-11 18:02:17 -0500
Processing by SubjectsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"actions"=>"index"}
```

Looks like you are redirecting to `GET /subjects/create` and passing in parameters `actions=index`, likely caused by this line in your controller:

```
redirect_to(:actions => 'index')
```

I think what you meant here was really `:action` (singular):

```
redirect_to(:action => 'index')
```

Regarding the issue with `:visible` not being saved, I can’t say much without knowing anything about the model, has `visible` been declared in the database schema?

Comment: Wow.That was it, don't know how I missed that. Thanks!